# Problemas con la semana 53 del 2024

Tags: c#, calendario

Tengo esta función:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat;
CalendarWeekRule calendarWeekRule = CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek;
int numeroDeSemana = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(fecha, dtfi.CalendarWeekRule, dtfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

y me dice que el

```
calendar.GetWeekOfYear("30/12/2024", dtfi.CalendarWeekRule, dtfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

es semana 53, cuando no es cierto. El resto del año me lo calcula bien, pero esta semana no, es semana 1.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: es posible que el problema este relacionado a tu configuracion cultural en donde este ejecutando la aplicacion.

Comment: puedes definir el calendario que desea utilizar con algo como: `CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        Calendar calendar = cultureInfo.Calendar;`

Answer (score 1):

`GetWeekOfYear` No devuelve el número de semanas como ISO 8601 que es lo que entiendo quieres hacer.

Puedes leer más sobre esto en:

[ISO 8601 Week of Year format in Microsoft .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/blogs/shawnste/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net)

La solución para .net core 3 y posterior, es usar `ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear`

*Ejemplo:*

```
DateTime f = Convert.ToDateTime("2024-12-30");
int numeroDeSemana = ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(f);
```

Para versiones anterior se puede usar la siguiente función, la cual
agrega 3 días en el caso que sea Lunes, martes o miércoles.

*Ejemplo:*

```
public static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
{
    DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
    if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        time = time.AddDays(3);
    }
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

Comment: duda!!! pero si le agrega tres dias al fin del año, se va al otro año, igual le va a devolver semana 54????

Comment: yo voy a esperar que el OP me responda XD

Comment: @gbianchi No hay ningún año con 54 semanas!!! Normalmente tienen 52 y algunos años 53. Hay muchas formas de contar semanas, y por supuesto en EEUU lo hacen fuera del estándar (que ahí está el problema). En el estandard ISO la primera semana puede contener días del año pasado, por eso el día "30/12/2024"`es la semana 1 del año 2025

Comment: La primera semana en el estándar ISO es la primera semana que contiene el primer jueves, el 1 de enero 2025 es jueves y por eso los días lunes ,martes y miércoles (29,30 y31 de dic respectivamente) corresponden a la semana 1 del 2025

Comment: no solo no vote, si no que le deje una duda, y mi duda es erronea.. igual, mas alla de mi fallo, era por otro motivo la duda.. de que no le diera la ultima semana, si no la primera del año siguiente...

Comment: @gbianchi y quedó clarificada la duda ??

Comment: a mi si... y que raro que sea ma única forma... por que las librerías de terceros hacen los mismo...

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera saber si: *Has pensado en obtener el ultimo domingo del año y posterior a ello indicar que si el dia que has puesto en la fecha es superior al ultimo domingo corresponde a la semana 1.*

si no lo has pensando al leer la pregunta pense en esa solución, por supuesto deberas aplicar ciertas validaciones para el caso de que utilices una fecha anterior. Espero pueda servirte.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime("30-12-2024");
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();      
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat;
    int numeroSemana = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(fecha, dtfi.CalendarWeekRule, dtfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
    DateTime ultimoDomingo = ObtenerUltimoDomingoDelAnno(fecha.Year);

    if (fecha.Day > ultimoDomingo.Day)
        numeroSemana = 1;         

    Console.WriteLine(numeroSemana);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
static DateTime ObtenerUltimoDomingoDelAnno(int anno)
{
    DateTime ultimaFechaDelAnio = new DateTime(anno, 12, 31);
    int diaDeLaSemana = (int)ultimaFechaDelAnio.DayOfWeek;
    int diasHastaUltimoDomingo = (diaDeLaSemana - (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday + 7) % 7;
    DateTime ultimoDomingo = ultimaFechaDelAnio.AddDays(-diasHastaUltimoDomingo);
    return ultimoDomingo;
}
```